# 6 GB RAM Fails in Vectorizing text using Word2Vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, bigdata, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to do one basic tweet sentiment analysis using word2vec and tfidf-score on a dataset consisting of 1,6M tweets but my 6 GB Gforce-Nvidia fails to do so. since this is my first practice project relating machine learning I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong because dataset is all text it shouldn't take this much RAM which makes my laptop froze in tweet2vec function or giving Memory Error in scaling part. below is part of my code that everything collapses.
the last thing is that I've tried with up to 1M data and it worked! so I'm curious what causes the problem

```
# --------------- calculating word weight for using later in word2vec model & bringing words together ---------------
def word_weight(data):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, use_idf=True)
    d = dict()
    for index in tqdm(data, total=len(data), desc='Assigning weight to words'):
        # --------- try except caches the empty indexes ----------
        try:
            matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform([w for w in index])
            tfidf = dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), vectorizer.idf_))
            d.update(tfidf)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    print("every word has weight now\n"
          "--------------------------------------")
    return d


# ------------------- bringing tokens with weight to recreate tweets ----------------
def tweet2vec(tokens, size, tfidf):
    count = 0
    for index in tqdm(tokens, total=len(tokens), desc='creating sentence vectors'):
        # ---------- size is the dimension of word2vec model (200) ---------------
        vec = np.zeros(size)
        for word in index:
            try:
                vec += model[word] * tfidf[word]
            except KeyError:
                continue
        tokens[count] = vec.tolist()
        count += 1
    print("tweet vectors are ready for scaling for ML algorithm\n"
          "-------------------------------------------------")
    return tokens


dataset = read_dataset('training.csv', ['target', 't_id', 'created_at', 'query', 'user', 'text'])
dataset = delete_unwanted_col(dataset, ['t_id', 'created_at', 'query', 'user'])
dataset_token = [pre_process(t) for t in tqdm(map(lambda t: t, dataset['text']),
                                              desc='cleaning text', total=len(dataset['text']))]

print('pre_process completed, list of tweet tokens is returned\n'
      '--------------------------------------------------------')
X = np.array(tweet2vec(dataset_token, 200, word_weight(dataset_token)))
print('scaling vectors ...')
X_scaled = scale(X)
print('features scaled!')
```

the data given to word_weight function is a (1599999, 200) shaped list which each index is consisted of pre-processed tweet tokens.
I appreciate your time and answer in advance and of course I'm glad to hear better approaches for handling big datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was solved when i changed the code (tweet2vec function) to this
(w is word weight)

```
def tweet2vec(tokens, size, tfidf):
    # ------------- size is the dimension of word2vec model (200) ---------------
    vec = np.zeros(size).reshape(1, size)
    count = 0
    for word in tokens:
        try:
            vec += model[word] * tfidf[word]
            count += 1
        except KeyError:
            continue
    if count != 0:
        vec /= count
    return vec

X = np.concatenate([tweet2vec(token, 200, w) for token in tqdm(map(lambda token: token, dataset_token),
                                                               desc='creating tweet vectors',
                                                               total=len(dataset_token))]
```

)

I have no idea why!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, it works with 1M tweets, but fails with 1.6M tweets? So you know the code is correct.

If the GPU is running out of memory when you think it shouldn't, it may be holding on from a previous process. Use [`nvidia-smi`](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface) to check what processes are using the GPU, and how much memory. If (before you run your code) you spot python processes in there holding a big chunk, it could be a crashed process, or a Jupyter window still open, etc.

I find it useful to `watch nvidia-smi` (not sure if there is a windows equivalent), to see how GPU memory changes as training progresses. Normally a chunk is reserved at the start, and then it stays fairly constant. If you see it rising linearly, something could be wrong with the code (are you re-loading the model on each iteration, something like that?).

Comment: the thing is i free up memory as much as I can and the used RAM is about 2GB before running the code but when my code reaches tweet2vec function my laptop is absolutely useless and you cant do anything with it I've tried with another laptop that has 8GB RAM and it returned Memory error in scaling part. the exact amount of data before my laptop freezes is (1373567). as for the code I have no idea what could be wrong with it since it works on lower data!!!

Comment: i should correct my comment everything is fine until 1373567th data(in tweet2vec function), and the data shouldn't have a problem because its shuffled every time code runs and as for the model if you mean the attribute i should say no because model just gives the vectors for the given word